# Split long string into multiple dataframe columns while not splitting across a word

Tags: r, tidyr

I am able to split a long string into 40 char columns using the following:

```
temp_df <- data.frame(
  long_string_column = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Whatever ornare nunc tellus, nec convallis enim viverra sit amet."
)


library(tidyr)
temp_df_new <- separate(temp_df, 
         long_string_column, 
         into = c("split1", "split2", "split3", "split4", "split5"), 
         sep = c(40, 80, 120, 160),
         remove = FALSE)
```

However this splits across words and can result in half the word being in one column and the other half being in the next.

[image]

Is there anyway to ensure that splitting across words doesn't occur?

Comment: Please add a sample of your [data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_wrap()` and separate on the newline characters.  This will avoid breaking up words and should result in the new columns having <= 40 characters each (although there may be exceptions depending on the nature of the original strings).

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

temp_df <- temp_df %>%
  mutate(tmp = str_wrap(long_string_column, 40))

cols <- seq(max(str_count(temp_df$tmp, "\n") + 1))

temp_df %>%
  separate(tmp, 
           into = paste0("split_", cols), 
           sep = "\n",
           remove = FALSE) %>%
  select(-tmp)
```